# Safely delete conda files from AWS deep learning AMI

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, deep-learning, anaconda

I started up "Deep Learning AMI (Ubuntu 18.04) Version 27.0"; it comes with a 90GB disk, which seemed plenty, but over 60GB of that was already used. I only need python3, pytorch, cuda.

I found 30GB was inside `~/anaconda3/envs`:

```
3.9G    aws_neuron_mxnet_p36
2.2G    aws_neuron_pytorch_p36
1.9G    aws_neuron_tensorflow_p36
2.5G    chainer_p27
1.2G    chainer_p36
2.1G    mxnet_p27
2.1G    mxnet_p36
729M    python2
866M    python3
2.5G    pytorch_p27
2.6G    pytorch_p36
2.2G    tensorflow2_p27
2.1G    tensorflow2_p36
2.3G    tensorflow_p27
1.8G    tensorflow_p36
31G total
```

Is it safe to just `rm`, say, the `tensorflow` and `mxnet` directories?

`conda env list` gives the same list. Is it better to do e.g. `conda env remove tensorflow2_p27`.

Are there likely to be any side effects of removing those packages? Is there a way to make sure nothing else depends on them before removing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was safe. I used the following commands (note the `-n` is needed), and Pytorch, used with Python3 and cuda continued to work.

```
conda env remove -n tensorflow2_p27
conda env remove -n tensorflow_p27
conda env remove -n mxnet_p27
conda env remove -n mxnet_p36
conda env remove -n chainer_p27
conda env remove -n chainer_p36
```

After each step it asked if it was okay to delete a bunch of packages.

That freed up about 10GB, which gave me the buffer I needed. (So I didn't experiment deleting some of the others, but I'm fairly sure all the aws_neuron ones could have gone too.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do a bunch of uninstalling of stuff, odds are you are using the wrong AMI for you.

If you don't want these services, I would select a different AMI that doesn't include these and then in the "User Data" section (bottom of step 3 in the EC2 launch wizard) include bash code to install/configure the software you want.

You can also change the storage size in step 4 of the launch wizard.